# Setting coordinate systems in gvSIG: workflow or transformation issues

Tags: coordinate-system, gvsig

I am learning how to use gvSIG 1.10 (Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard). My goal is to create a simple county map of Illinois using the base data shapefiles available from the [Illinois Natural Resources Geospatial Data Clearinghouse](http://www.isgs.uiuc.edu/nsdihome/webdocs/st-basem.html).

I want to use a state plane coordinate system such as NAD83/Illinois (West) so that the layer will look like this (narrow):

[image: Illinois]

... not this (wide):

[image: Illinois wide]

Here are the dialogs I see after adding the layer:

[image]

I tried to change the projection to the desired "narrow" version, but no matter what I do, it is always displayed as the undesired "wide" version.

In case this is relevant, here's the empty Transformations list in gvSIG:

[image: Transformation dialog]

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a software component?

Answer (score 1):

You are using gvSIG 1.10, have you tried to update to 1.12? Here you have some instructions for MacOS

http://gvsigmac.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/gvsig-112-for-mac-107-and-108.html

You can also ask Agustín there, he's very nice and helpful.

Comment: Thank you Jorge, but v 1.12 appears to be compatible with only Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) and 10.8 (Mountain Lion). I use Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard). (And upon closer inspection, I'm actually using gvSIG v 1.11; it's mislabeled 1.10.) gvSIG appears to be the last version made for OS 10.6. Do you know if development has stopped for Mac OS 10.6? Or should I ask Agustín?